# Invalid Table Name Created When Using Import Local File

Tags: sql, hana

I have created a table using HANA Studio Import Local File.
The table has loaded and I can Preview it (shows up on the explorer bar on the left).
However when I try to

```
drop table <tablename>
```

I get an "invalid table name" error.

However, if I create a table using

```
create column table <tablename> ( ... )
```

Everything is fine and I can "drop" it.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**:

There seems to be a difference between row and column tables.
Import Local File creates a row table and I can create a column table with the same exact name.

I can delete the tables using  Delete Object Cascade
But still wondering why Drop Table will not work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems when I was manually creating a table with

```
create column table my_schema.my_table_name
```

the my_schema is lower case and fine, however with Import Local File, HANA Studio uses

```
"MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE_NAME"
```

and it becomes case sensitive for some reason, so my_schema.my_table_name would not work AND the names need to be in quotes...

Comment: That’s only partly right. It’s correct that unquoted identifiers get automatically converted to upper case. That does not require quotes though. So, `DROP TABLE my_schema.my_table_name` will work if the table name is actually upper case.